# Finding value when multiple rows by group by

Tags: sql

Lets say we have the following data sets

tbl_building:

```
id   --       name

1    --       building 1
2    --       building 2
```

tbl_rooms:

```
id -- building_id -- room_id -- light_status

1   ------   1         -------------        1      -----------     0
2   ------   1         -------------        2      -----------     1
3   ------   1         -------------        3      -----------     0
4   ------   2         -------------        1      -----------     1
```

How would I construct a single sql statement to find out which BUILDINGS have a light switched on in a YES/NO format Whilst grouping by Building name

Idealling I want something like the following:

```
SELECT b.name, if(light_status, 'yes', no) as light_status
FROM tbl_building b
JOIN tbl_rooms r on b.id = r.building_id
group by b.id
```

However, this seems to be random as to which room it will bring back for each buildinh

Comment: Do a JOIN, and ORDER BY light_status

Comment: in your example, first building has 3 rooms, 1 is on and two is off... so what should be the expected output? building light is switched on or off?

Comment: Schema clearly shows light status is relevant to individual room and not whole building. What does s/w requirement say for a case where a building has 1 room with lights On and 1 with lights Off.?

Comment: you want number of room that light status in on and group by building name right ? for your query not contain aggregate function

Comment: Show us the result you want!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Select b.name, case when sum (a.light_status) > 0 then 'YES' else 'NO'  end as LightStatus
From tbl_rooms a
Join tbl_buildings b
On a.building_id = b.building_id
Group by b.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.name
FROM tbl_rooms A
INNER JOIN tbl_builiding B
ON A.building_id = B.id
```

Comment: Why do you need to perform a group by operation? It does not make any sense or might be i m not understanding your output result. If i am not wrong your output should say that building 1 and building 2 have lights on. I just added room_id column if you need more details from your output.

Comment: I have been asked to provide a list of buliding and whether or not they have a light still on. The requestee has asked me to display all buildings

Comment: but what about building 1? ive ran that query at it saying that there is no lights on, when there is one room with a light active

Answer (score 0):

A simple case for a semi-join:

```
SELECT name
FROM tbl_building b
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tbl_rooms r
    WHERE b.id = r.building_id
    AND light_status = 1
)
```

This will return those buildings where at least one room has their light switched on.

Answer (score 0):

```
select (case when tbl_rooms.light_status = 1 then building_id end) as building_id_on,
 (case when tbl_rooms.light_status = 0 then building_id end) as building_id_on
from tbl_building inner join tbl_rooms on tbl_building.id = tbl_rooms.building_id
```

Comment: could you please format this so that it is easier to read and also explain how this code achieves what the OP is trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

To find buildings with at least one room with the lights turned on:

```
SELECT
B.name
FROM tbl_rooms A
INNER JOIN tbl_builiding B
ON A.building_id = B.id
GROUP BY B.name
HAVING MAX(light_status) = 1
```

To list all buildings and wether or not they have at least one room with the light turned on:

```
SELECT
B.name, IIF(MAX(light_status) = 1, 'YES', 'NO') as light_status
FROM tbl_rooms A
INNER JOIN tbl_builiding B
ON A.building_id = B.id
GROUP BY B.name
```